# The code works. But besides that, there is an error. Why and how to fix it?

Tags: ruby

The code works. But besides that, there is an error. Why and how to fix it?

```
def make_casserole
    puts "Preheat oven to 375 degrees"
    ingredients = yield
    puts "Place #{ingredients} in dish"
    puts "Bake for 20 minutes"
end

make_casserole do 
  "noodles, celery, and tuna"
end

make_casserole do 
  "rice, broccoli, and chicken"
end

make_casserole

blocc.rb:31:in `make_casserole': no block given (yield) (LocalJumpError)from blocc.rb:45:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Well, what is the expected output if no ingredients are given as in your last `make_casserole` call? How should the method behave without a block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must change the line `ingredients = yield` to `ingredients = yield if block_given?`. This is because you invoke the method without passing a block. The method cannot yield if `no block given`.